# How do I place elements next to each other with CSS

Tags: css, html

I am trying to place two elements next to each other using CSS. One element has the class of left where I float left and the other has a class of right which I would like place to the right of the left element. I'm trying to get it to look like [this](http://www.intro-webdesign.com/CSS/assignment-2/index.jpg) image. My full code can be seen at [this](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/qveyeJ) codepen. Thank you.

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 2%;
}

header {
    background-color: #606060;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

aside {
    background-color: #ffcc80;
}

aside img {
    width: 150px;
    margin: 20px;
    display: block;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    float: right;
}

a {
    color: #000000;
}

.right a {
    color: #0000FF;
}

nav {

}

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 22%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    padding: 10px;
}

.active {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

HTML

```
<aside class = "left">
            <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_17.jpg"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Ultimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_19.jpg" alt="Creative Common Ultimate Photo" title="By Ed Yourdon [CC BY-SA 2.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)], via Wikimedia Commons"/></a>

            <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"><img alt="Ultimate Frisbee Colorado Cup 2005" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7d/Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg/512px-Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"/></a>

            <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/paradisecoastie/15409853738/" title="Ultimate Frisbee"><img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3948/15409853738_7dbfbfbac7_k.jpg"  alt="Ultimate Frisbee"></a>
        </aside>
<section class = "right">
                <h2>Watch your Head </h2>
            <p>Ultimate Frisbee is a sport that I never played myself, but it's popularity is something hard to ignore in many Midwestern college towns.  Students (and people who wish they were still students) spend the few briefs months of good weather, sprinting down fields, hurling frisbees, and yelling "Stack!!".</p>
            <p>What I find much more entertaining is the large number of people who continue to play when the weather gets windy and the night sky darkens around oh....4:15pm.  The sight of frisbees boomeranging in the wind is topped only by the knowledge that even when you can't seem, those same plastic discs of death are probably hurtling through the dark night sky at 8 or 9 o'clock in the evening.
            </p>
            <p>Ultimate Frisbee requires a great deal of stamina and dexterity.  Not surprisingly, the <abbr title = "International Olympic Committee">IOC</abbr> officially recognized Ultimate as a sport in 2015.   It can go up against other sports for inclusion in  Olympic games.</p>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `display: inline-block` that should work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why use float left and float right.
U can use float left for both. the will align next to each other if there is enough space.

I think flexbox will be a better solution for you with this project
(content section and sidemenu).
It will save you al lot of issues with the height and responsive with.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/